# A basis for $\{(x-y,y-z,z-x) : (x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The original question :

Prove that $F: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ such that $F(x,y,z)=(x-y,y-z,z-x)$ is a linear-map and find a basis for $imF$ and $kerF$.

My try :
I proved that $F$ holds the two conditions of being linear.  Also, It was easy to find a basis for $kerF=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x=y=z\}$ ( The basis is $(1,1,1)$. )

The part i'm stuck on :

I know that $dim(\mathbb R^3)=dim(imF)+dim(kerF)$ . So, a basis for $imF$ should have $2$ members.  The problem is that i don't know what it is. I mean, i don't know which members of $\mathbb R^3$ are spanned by $imF$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(1,1,1)$ is not the basis of $\mathrm{im} F$, it's the basis of $\ker F$.

Comment: @5xum i'm gonna edit ... excuse me :)

Comment: Recommendation: try computing $F(1,0,0)$ and $F(0,1,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
im(F)&=\{(x-y,y-z,z-x) \mid x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
&=\{x(1,0,-1)+y(-1,1,0)+z(0,-1,1) \mid x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
&=span\{(1,0,-1),(-1,1,0),(0,-1,1)\}\\
&=span\{(1,0,-1),(-1,1,0)\}\\
\end{align}

Show that $\{(1,0,-1),(-1,1,0)\}$ is linearly independent and you've got yourself a basis.

There's general way to figure out a basis for a spanning set which involves building a matrix whose rows are the vectors spanning the set, and then subsequently row reducing the matrix.

Comment: Right upon first glance it may seem like $F$ generates all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and is onto, but it clearly isn't.

Comment: We know that $im(F)\neq \mathbb{R}^3$, since $ker(F)\neq 0$